# Self-destructing comments

Tags: feature-request, comments

Why isn't there (and can we add) a feature to have comments that delete themselves after they are read by the recipient, allowing people to thank each other without clogging up the screen with comments?

Comment: There is such a feature, called deleting comments when they are no longer necessary, and/or flagging them when they are unnecessary.  As mentioned (comments to https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4551/comment-character-limit), just thanking someone is not usually considered to be a useful comment on SE